# Did I manage to post an answer twice, or what?

Tags: support

[Am I in danger if a project component is relicensed?](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/1608/am-i-in-danger-if-a-project-component-is-relicensed)

A few times in my SE history, I've gotten tangled up in a particular oddity of the editing UI and ended up with a duplicated answer. Did I do that here and Zizouz cleaned up after me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I cleared that answer up for you.

The second answer had been raised to my attention through a flag, by another community member. You had posted 2 answers: which were duplicates of each other, however, one of them included an extra paragraph. Call me Speedy Gonzales, I'll catch you before you can catch yourself :)

Comment: thanks; this happens sometimes from clicking on the 'formatted preview' instead of the actual edit box.

Comment: @bmargulies No problem! Don't worry about it :)